# How to create a dropdown that is dependent on the value of another in Unity GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a dropdown that will allow me to change the type of controller my game is expecting to show the correct controls. I have a dropdown that has two options, those being keyboard & mouse, and controller. I am trying to create a dropdown to change between Xbox and PlayStation controllers that only appears when the Input Type dropdown is set to "Controller"

I have tried to create a script that allows me to do this, but as I am new-ish to c# programming, I have not gotten very far.

Comment: you need a custom Editor implementation for this ... hard to help though without knowing any of your types and so far implementation ....

Comment: Do you mean at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Dropdown Menu in the Unity Inspector or somewhere in the scene?

Given it is in your scene somewhere and you have two dropdowns, one for the Input and one for the ControllerInput:

On default, only the Input Dropdown should be active. That dropdown Menu could throw an event when the value of it changed. With another method you could check if that value matches your Controller Input and if so it should activate the second Dropdown where you choose between Playstation and Xbox Controller.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameControllerSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dropdown inputTypeDropdown;
    public Dropdown controllerTypeDropdown;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Subscribe to the OnValueChanged event of the inputTypeDropdown
        inputTypeDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnInputTypeChanged);

        // Set the initial state based on the default value of the inputTypeDropdown
        OnInputTypeChanged(inputTypeDropdown.value);
    }

    private void OnInputTypeChanged(int value)
    {
        // Check the selected value of the inputTypeDropdown
        string selectedInputType = inputTypeDropdown.options[value].text;

        // Toggle the visibility of the controllerTypeDropdown based on the selected input type
        controllerTypeDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(selectedInputType == "Controller");

        // Optionally, you can reset the controllerTypeDropdown value to 0 when hiding it
        if (selectedInputType != "Controller")
        {
            controllerTypeDropdown.value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```